# Difference between FROM and JOIN tables

Tags: mysql

I'm working through [the JOIN tutorial](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation) on SQL zoo.

Let's say I'm about to execute the code below:

```
SELECT a.stadium, COUNT(g.matchid)
FROM game a 
JOIN goal g 
ON g.matchid = a.id
GROUP BY a.stadium
```

As it happens, it produces the same output as the code below:

```
SELECT a.stadium, COUNT(g.matchid)
FROM goal g  
JOIN game a
ON g.matchid = a.id
GROUP BY a.stadium
```

So then, when does it matter which table you assign at FROM and which one you assign at JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using an `INNER JOIN` like you are here, the order doesn't matter. That is because you are connecting two tables on a common index, so the order in which you use them is up to you. You should pick an order that is most logical to you, and easiest to read. A habit of mine is to put the table I'm selecting from first. In your case, you're selecting information about a stadium, which comes from the game table, so my preference would be to put that first.

In other joins, however, such as `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` the order will matter. That is because these joins will select all rows from one table. Consider for example I have a table for `Students` and a table for `Projects`. They can exist independently, some students may have an associated project, but not all will.

If I want to get all students and project information while still seeing students without projects, I need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.name, p.project
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN project p ON p.student_id = s.id;
```

Note here, that the `LEFT JOIN` refers to the table in the `FROM` clause, so that means ALL of students were being selected. This also means that `p.project` will be null for some rows. Order matters here.

If I took the same concept with a `RIGHT JOIN`, it will select all rows from the table in the join clause. So if I changed the query to this:

```
SELECT s.name, p.project
FROM student s
RIGHT JOIN project p ON p.student_id = s.id;
```

This will return all rows from the project table, regardless of whether or not it has a match for students. This means that in some rows, `s.name` will be null. Similar to the first example, because I've made `project` the outer joined table, `p.project` will never be null (assuming it isn't in the original table). In the first example, `s.name` should never be null.

In the case of outer joins, order will matter. Thankfully, you can think intuitively with `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins. A left join will return all rows in the table to the left of that statement, while a right join returns all rows from the right of that statement. Take this as a rule of thumb, but be careful. You might want to develop a pattern to be consistent with yourself, as I mentioned earlier, so these queries are easier for you to understand later on.

Answer (score 1):

When you only JOIN 2 tables, usually the order does not matter: MySQL scans the tables in the optimal order.

When you scan more than 2 tables, the order could matter:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
JOIN b ON ...
JOIN c ON ...
```

Also, MySQL tries to scan the tables in the fastest way (large tables first). But if a join is slow, it is possible that MySQL is scanning them in a non-optimal order. You can verify this with `EXPLAIN`. In this case, you can force the join order by adding the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The order doesn't always matter, I usually just order it in a way that makes sense to someone reading your query.

Sometime order does matter. Try it with `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you are using an `INNER JOIN`, if you're expecting a match on a common ID or foreign key, it probably doesn't matter too much.

You would however need to specify the tables the correct way round if you were performing an `OUTER JOIN`, as not all records in this type of join are guaranteed to match via the same field.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will matter when you will user another join `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`
currently You are using `NATURAL JOIN` that is return all tables related data, if JOIN table row not match then it will exclude row from result

If you use **LEFT / RIGHT {OUTER}** join then result will be different, follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins) for more detail